# horizontal scrollbar on div with dynamic content and overflow-y hidden

Tags: html, css, dynamic, scrollbar, overflow

I need to have a div with one line of images, the amount of images inside the div can be changed at any time. So I want I horizontal scrollbar.
I have a structure like the following. I tried to achieve it with css, but unfortanetly it doesn't work.

```
<div id="scroll-wrapper">
  <div id="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumbnail-container active">
      <img src="foobar" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
      <img src="bar" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code with CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/c622c3w9/2/

Note that I do not want a solution with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the `float: left` to get scroll to work

```
 #thumbnails {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  max-height: 50px;
  min-width: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll; /*add this so you get bottom scrollbar*/
  white-space: nowrap; /*add this to stop images wrapping so thay stay on one line*/
}

.thumbnail-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 5px;
  border: 2px solid steelblue;
  margin: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left; remove this otherwise scroll will not work*/
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c622c3w9/3/

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do two things.   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93dgt4en/).

```
.thumbnail-container {
  .......
  // float: left;     <== Remove
}

#thumbnails {
  .....
  white-space: nowrap;   // Add
}
```